# [[scopes]] and the execution context

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

When we execute the following code

```
var addTo = (passed) =>{
    var add = (inner) => {
    var foo = () => {
        return inner + passed
    }
    return foo;
    }
  return add;
}


var addThree = addTo(3)(5);

console.dir(addThree);
```

We get the following in chrome devtools:

[image]

I understand what a closure is and why the first closure displays 5 and the second closure is displaying 3. I seem to get the concepts of closure and execution context (stack) now but don't know how they are exactly related.

1. Is [[scopes]] just a representation of the scope chain?
2. Is this at all related to the execution context?
3. Is there a link between the execution context and closures?

Comment: What do you understand by the term "execution context"?

Comment: The execution context is a stack, it starts at global and everytime a function is called a new context is added on the stack (with value of this, and all variables/scope chain) if a value is return a context is popped of the stack

Comment: is this right??

Comment: Yes, an execution context is a stack frame. Just wanted to confirm that before answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is [[scopes]] just a representation of the scope chain?

Yes.

> Is this at all related to the execution context?

Yes. When the function is called (like `addThree()`), the new execution context will create its local function scope to inherit from the parent [[scopes]].

> Is there a link between the execution context and closures?

Nothing special. The currently active lexical environment, i.e. the (block) scope, is more relevant for the creation of closures.